# Как хранить информацию о позициях в заказе?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Добрый день.
Проектирую Базу данных для интернет магазина.

Спроектировал следующие таблицы:

**orders**:

- `id`
- `status_id`
- `user_id`
- `comment`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

**product**:

- `id`
- `name`
- и т.д.

**order_product** (созданная *Doctrine* для реализации связи many-to-many):

- `order_id`
- `product_id`

На этом этапе я застрял. Как мне хранить информацию о конкретных позициях в заказе? Например, мне надо фиксировать, что конкретного продукта заказали конкретное количество и зафиксировать на тот момент его цену.

Comment: Попробовал решить вопрос дублирование записи  order_id product_id в таблице order_product т. е. если в заказе два товара одного наименования, то записывать в табличку два раза. В итоге получил ошибку SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Если вопрос в том, чтобы правильно задизайнить схему данных, то я хз, как в русском СО, но на всемирном это считается офф-топиком (там скинут ссылку на ресурс, куда надо такое постить). Если здесь это позволительно, то уж точно это не относится к [symfony] и [doctrine2], надо менять теги, заголовок и само тело вопроса. Вообще, правилами запрещено спрашивать советов. Это сайт вопрос-ответ. Надо задавать вопрос, на который, по идее, должен быть только один идеальный ответ.

Comment: Это относится именно к Doctrine и Symfony. Вопрос в реализации всего этого на уровне маппинга и содержимого action в контроллере.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли: по вашему вопросу вообще не понятно, чего Вы хотите. Что конкретно у вас не маппится? Что конкретно у вас в контроллере написано, что работает не так?

Comment: Конкретно пока всё маппится, но мне нужны не только поля product_id, order_id, а еще quantity и price, которые при записи many-to-many в orm.yml файле создать нельзя впринципе, но решения я вроде как нашел, но советоваться здесь нормальное оно или нет как я понял нельзя.

Comment: @Алексей, отнюдь! Хорошо оформленный вопрос с запросом [review](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/инспекция-кода/info) будет наверняка полезен. Гляньте описание метки и требования.

Answer (score 2):

В нормализованной БД данный паттерн обычно реализуется с помощью промежуточной таблицы, которая является реализацией атрибутивного отношения многие-ко-многим. В Вашем случае это будет доработанная таблица `order_product` с полями:

- order_id
- product_id
- current_price
- quantity
- discount (если есть скидки на отдельные позиции)
- product_title (на случай, если названия товаров поменяются через какое-то время)
- да и вообще любые данные о товаре, которые могут меняться со временем, но нужны в контексте заказа

Для определения данных полей Вам придется сделать дополнительную сущность, которую связать как с `product` (one-to-many), так и с `orders` (one-to-many)

Если смотреть на более модные ныне ненормализованные БД или вообще не реляционные, то тут надо смотреть конкретную СУБД с конкретной базой и прогонять на производительность. В среднем случае выигрываете.

Например, можно в сущность Заказа добавить поле `positions`, в котором уже держать JSON объект всех позиций со всеми деталями. Связи с `product` как таковой не будет, то есть constraint никакой не создастся, но если логика приложения на высоком уровне построена правильно, то косяков происходить не будет.